# I can't use my physical keyboard to type in uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I can't use my physical keyboard on typing in the **UITextField**. so, I'm just using the virtual keyboard in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Try after restart the simulator

Comment: Quit your simulator.OPen it again

Comment: I've had this a few times. You have to restart the simulator.

Comment: Delete derived data then quit simulator and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is bug in the simulator. Most of the time a quit and relaunch or a reset will works.

From Xcode release note

> iOS Simulator sometimes stops responding to hardware keyboard.
>   Quitting and relaunching the simulator usually corrects this. (14642684)

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on simulator and re-run project in Xcode. (Funny but it's a truth)

You are done.

This is most annoying bug in Simulator.

These days I get error as Simulator is in use even if that simulator is closed/ killed. LOL!

Comment: The most annoying bug for me is the black screen while try to launch your app. Then having to kill the simulator a few times to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

**Option 1:**

- **Alt + Rightclick + Force Quit** to quit your simulator. Now re run your
  code.

**Option 2:**
If its not resloved for long time means only try this option. 
**Note:** All contents in simulator will lose

```
Click iPhone Simulator  
           --> Goto iOS Simulator menu in finder 
                        --> Click Reset Content & Settings
```

Comment: Not ideal if you have apps on there and don't want to loose there data stored.

Comment: Never give `Click Reset Content & Settings` solution... it's last option.. it's like you are saying **YOU HAVE TO DIE**